# Crear matriz de tamaño variable dependiendo del tamaño del vector de entrada en python

Tags: python, matrices, numpy

tengo el siguiente problema en python. Yo doy un vector en numpy
que tiene un cierto número de elementos. Dicho número de elementos debe ser variable y representan las coordenadas x de un punto, tengo otro vector igual que representa a las coordenadas en y. Posteriormente le pido que con los datos de ambos vectores calcule la distancia entre el punto 1 y el 1, después el 1 con el 2, el 1 con el 3 y que los guarde en forma de matriz en la primer fila, a11, a12, a13 y a14. Después que repita para calcular la distancia entre el punto 2 con 1, luego el 2 con 2, el 2 con 3 y el 2 con 4 y lo coloque en la segunda fila creando a12, a22, a23 y a24 y así sucesivamente hasta conseguir la relación de distancias entre todos ellos formando una matriz que para este ejemplo debería ser de 4x4 (aunque recordar que se busca que la matriz ajuste su tamaño al numero de elementos en el vector)

```
import numpy as np


x=np.array([-1.5,1.5,-1.5,1.5])# vector de posición x que puede ser de tamaño variable
y=np.array([1.5,1.5,-1.5,-1.5])# vector de posición x que puede ser de tamaño variable
s=[] # aquí se alojan los resultados
for i in range (0,len(x)):
    for j in range (0,len(x)):
        s_1=((x[i]-x[j])**2+(y[i]-y[j])**2)**0.5 # se calculan las distancias
        s.append(s_1) # se alojan en como una sola lista, no como matriz
s=np.array(s) # se convierte en vector pero no en un vector de 4x4 como se desea
```

Cuando me devuelve los resutlados sí son los correctos pero me los devuelve en forma de vector de 1 x 16 y no en un vector de 4x4.

```
[0.         3.         3.         4.24264069 3.         0.
 4.24264069 3.         3.         4.24264069 0.         3.
 4.24264069 3.         3.         0.        ]
```

El valor que yo quisiera obtener es

```
[[0, 3, 3 , 4.24264069][3, 0, 4.24264090, 3][3, 4.24264090, 0, 3][4.24264069, 3, 3, 0]
```

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: te daré una pista, espero que no me borren xD
primero debes hacer append con los 4 calculos que haces, o sea 4 append, cuando termine eso debes hacer append al array "s" que declaraste con la operacion que hiciste anteriormente. todo eso solo seria 1 proceso en que agregaria datos el index 0 del array "S", lo siguiente seria una repeticion de lo anterior. espero que lo hayas entendido, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

utiliza `numpy.reshape`

después de que armaste tu `s=np.array(s)` usa la función:

```
np.reshape(s, (4,4))
```

Te da como resultado

```
array([[0.        , 3.        , 3.        , 4.24264069],
       [3.        , 0.        , 4.24264069, 3.        ],
       [3.        , 4.24264069, 0.        , 3.        ],
       [4.24264069, 3.        , 3.        , 0.        ]])
```

y si lo quieres variar sólo coloca `len(x)` en las dimensiones del `np.array` osea su `np.shape`, de la siguiente manera:

```
np.reshape(s, (len(x),len(x)))
```

Sin embargo!!!

Para evitar usar `np.reshape` sólo basta con agregar dos lineas de código a tu proceso:

```
import numpy as np

x=np.array([-1.5,1.5,-1.5,1.5])
y=np.array([1.5,1.5,-1.5,-1.5])
s=[] # aquí se alojan los resultados
for i in range (0,len(x)):
    k = [] # <- esto será la i-ésima fila
    for j in range (0,len(x)):
        s_1=((x[i]-x[j])**2+(y[i]-y[j])**2)**0.5 # se calculan las distancias
        k.append(s_1) # <- se alojan los resultados en la fila
    s.append(k) # <- se aloja la fila a s
```

Ahora tienes la siguiente lista

```
[[0.0, 3.0, 3.0, 4.242640687119285],
 [3.0, 0.0, 4.242640687119285, 3.0],
 [3.0, 4.242640687119285, 0.0, 3.0],
 [4.242640687119285, 3.0, 3.0, 0.0]]
```

y con `s = np.array(s)` se convierte la lista en una numpy matriz cuadrada.

Espero haberte ayudado

Comment: Bravo, eso si que funcionó. Gracias. ¿Una pregunta más, reshape es una herraminenta propia de numpy. ¿Como se podrá resolver de manera "tradicional"? (sin reshape, suponiendo que estamos en otro ambiente de programación distinto a python)

Comment: @moscosir `reshape` es un método de la clase (y por ende objetos) `numpy`, se puede hacer de forma tradicional pero es bastante trabajoso, si lo planeas hacer en un lenguaje distinto es mejor investigar si existe una librería  similar

Comment: entendido, gracias

Comment: @moscosir, revisa la edición. La verdad es que puedes evitar usar `np.reshape` agregando dos lineas de código a tu proceso. Por favor, si te funcionó, marca mi respuesta como la solución. Gracias y buen día.

Comment: ¿Una pregunta Alejo, si el numero que quieres ingresar en el método append es un numero complejo a+bi  siendo i la raíz de -1, el método desarrollado seguiría funcionando igual?

Comment: No creo que deba haber un problema, en Python puedes escribir `z = 1 + 2j` y luego escribe `type(z)` y te dirá que es un complejo. sin embargo estoy entendiendo en tu codigo que `x` sería la parte real y `y` la parte imaginaria de los números o puntos...

Comment: Digamos que el codigo tal como se respondió ya esta bien, sin embargo, hay un paso siguiente en el cual cada miembro de la matriz actual (que actualmente representa una distancia entnre x e y) será afectada por un número complejo lo cual dará pie a que esta actual matriz que se tiene se convierta en una matriz compleja . Es decir, no es que x sea una parte real y y la parte imaginaria, esos dos valores ya sirvieron a su propósito para calcular la distancia)

Comment: probablemente existe otro acercamiento a tu problema. No sé bien qué quieras hacer exactamente. Pero sí se pueden guardar números complejos en una matriz. por ejemplo `np.array([[2j, 1+3j, 6j + 2], [3j + 2, 1+1j, 2j]])
`

Comment: Esa parte lo se razonablemente bien, la parte problemática es trabajarlo en conjunto con el append y que la matriz sea de tamaño variable. La idea es manejar un ciclo for como en el ejemplo que motivo la pregunta original pero manejándolo todo con números complejos. Esta noche lo intentaré a ver si funciona. En otras palabras, ¿El append, acepta números complejos?

Comment: Sí acepta números complejos. Como ves en el ejemplo, incluso acepta listas y otros tipos de datos u objetos. Eso es lo bonito de las listas en Python.